# Does my gravel bike fit me?

Tags: bike-fit, gravel

[image]Hi does this bike fit me? Im 5’7 (1.7 m) with a 31 in (79 cm) inseam on a size medium

Comment: Your seat seems too low, but a different position would be necessary to be sure. You should not have your knee bent when touching the pedal with your heel in the lowest position but you should also not  need to rock your pelvis.

Comment: Ok so you think it’s the right sized frame but I need to do a few adjustments? It’s the ball of my foot that is touching the peddle

Comment: I cannot comment on the frame size.

Comment: I’d raise the saddle and get a longer stem.

Comment: @Michael suggests this since he thinks you are too upright. If you get further down, for instance by bending your elbows (you need to roll your wrist out a bit for that) the reach would fit you much better. However, I assume you plan to ride somewhat upright since getting flatter requires quite a lot of power and strength. A good fit for a relaxed position will be very different from a good fit for a faster position. You have to decide which way to go.

Comment: @gachenk I’m looking to do a lot of off road so I’m guessing I need a more relaxed position?

Comment: I read your question as (a) "_I just bought this bike, I haven't rolled with it outside yet, and the store will exchange it if needed within 30 days. Should I keep this frame or move to the larger/smaller size?_" whereas the comments/answer so far mostly address the question (b) "_Is my present position on this particular frame correct, and if not how might I modify settings (saddle height, saddle fore-aft, handlebar angle, stem length) to improve my position?_" Could you clarify that you're really after (b) and not (a)?

Comment: I think I’m after the best position tbh. I have a feeling it’s the right size

Comment: I think you should move your shifters down a bit, so they're more level with the ground. Your wrists look like they're bent vertically towards you.

Comment: You have lots of mixed opinions here. I want to reassure you that the bike looks very much the right size but needs some minor adjustments to get the best fit. Unfortunately noone can judge these from a static position, much less a photo! Anyone who is saying otherwise probably doesn't have a clue. See if you can find an independant fitter or local shop to do a quick set up for you. The AlpKit bikes are nice but the disadvantage of not buying from a bricks n mortar shop is that you have to do the setup yourself or find someone to help you.

Comment: Thank you for this! @Noise

Answer (score 2):

Some observations:

- Your bars are probably too wide for you. The way your wrist roll inward indicate this. This leads to numbness in your nerves, ulnar squeezing, and shoulder pain as you might hunch your shoulders. The trend is to make gravel bars very wide to help with leverage with big tyres in heavy terrain. Most gravel riders though have lighter tyres (like your panaracers) and ride on easy gravel. Bars should be chosen like on an endurance bike. Never wider than your shoulders.
- Your bike is too long for the relaxed position in your photo (45 degree upright). You have a very short stem, but your arms are still stretched out too much. You can see that very well at your shoulders that are very much hunched. You also seem to have moved your saddle forward. This makes handling worse (too much weight forward) and puts much more force on your hands. This is not easy to fix since you already have a very short stem. Maybe the bike frame is just too long. You could get bars with less reach, yours seem to be quite long (distance hoods to tops). By getting lower you also get more reach. By straightening your shoulders this might even reduce shoulder pain a bit. However, you need more core strength and most likely do not have enough power to lift you up. In effect you'd be in a permanent plank and will get arm fatigue and pain.
- Most likely people will tell you your saddle is too low. Ignore them, it's an old knee jerk reflex to advise increasing saddle height. Have someone cycle behind you and let them watch for (a) your hips rolling from side to side (b) you sitting slightly askew on the saddle to get your shorter leg closer to the pedal. If any of that happens lower your saddle. Otherwise you are fine. In case you want to increase your saddle height do it in very small increments, have someone do the previous check, ride a bit and check again.

Comment: Ok thank you. Could I not tilt the handle bars towards me more? So that I’m closer to the huds?

Comment: The inward wrist roll is probably related to the silly flared bars and brifters turned drastically inward rather than the width of the bars.  It's more a design fault than a fit issue.  I agree the reach is too long and the saddle height probably OK.  +1

Comment: So you think a small would suit me better?

Comment: @NiallCarlyle-Reid i'm not an expert in bike fitting, it's only my opinion, so didn't write my own answer.  But yes, i think a size smaller would reduce you stretching for the bars and allow a bend in the elbow, whilst at the same time making a slightly less upright position due to the lower stack height.

Comment: Thanks Andy I’m just a bit worried that my inseam will be too long for a smaller frame

Comment: @AndyP on handle bar width: https://youtu.be/bYjvsg-ztmo

Comment: @NiallCarlyle-Reid your bars should be flat, you can lift the brifters up a bit by sliding them a few mm up on the bars, that gets your wrists in a better position. However, you'd need to re-tape the bars.

Comment: @NiallCarlyle-Reid getting new bars is not a terribly expensive thing. Look for correct width, very short reach. Most modern bars and brifters go well for braking. So avoid classic bars or old ergo bar styles. Best go to a shop and hold a few. Often you can ask for a cheap aluminium version of the same bars if the shop only stocks expensive carbon.

Comment: It's worth trying a lower overall position. Put the stem low and bars flat. Lean forward without touching the bars, balancing on the pedals and saddle, to feel the point where your glutes (back of your legs) engage with your core to support your upper body. If you have good core strength this can be a more comfortable lower back position, but only if you're set long and low enough to engage the leg muscles. At least, that's what my fitter did for me!